# onclick на теге <p>

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Необходимо посадить событие с помощью атрибута `onclick` на тег `<p>`. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в данном случае функция не вызывается?

```js
function close() {
   console.log('click');
}
```

```html
<p onclick="close()">Клик</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close` - [зарезервированное слово](http://www.w3bai.com/ru/js/js_reserved.html).

```js
function MyClose() {
   console.log('click');
}
```

```html
<p onclick="MyClose()">Клик</p>
```